# Get file type from the "asksaveasfilename" function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename` function in a GUI. The following is the code:

```
def onSaveImage(self):
    ftypes = [('PNG', '*.png'), ('JPEG', '*.jpg'), ('PDF', '*.pdf')]
    imagefname = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=self, filetypes = ftypes)
```

The function to save the file is deduced from the filename extension. Is there a more elegant way to get the users choice of *file type* from the file dialog itself?

Comment: You could use the mimetypes module.

Comment: You want to know which file extension was used by the user to store the file? Why you don't simply store the file's name in a variable?

Comment: @Rinzler That is what I'm doing right now and what is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @tmartin As far as I know, there is no other way to know the extension of the file stored.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe now it's late but
Try to set defaultextension

```
saveDirectory=asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*",filetypes = (("JPEG files","*.jpg"),('all files','*.*')))
```

you'll get the result is the filename following by the the users choice of file type